# Deleting a user selected column in a html table using javascript ( no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I have implement the following code to delete a column in a html table. I want to be able to implement this when the user selects a certain column rather than just the last column being deleted all the time - can anyone help ?

```
function deleteColumn(){

  var lastColumn = document.getElementById('Overall Result');
  var table = document.getElementById('tg-LTO9U');
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
     table.rows[i].deleteCell(table.rows[i].cells.length-2);
  }
}
```

Delete Column

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add relevant HTML - you likely want `table.rows[i].deleteCell(3)` where 3 is the 4th cell

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED 2021

Delegate instead

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable")
  table.querySelectorAll("th").forEach((th, i) => th.innerHTML += ` <sup><a href="#" data-idx="${i}" class="del" >X</a></sup>`);
  
  table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("a");
    if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("del")) {
      const idx = tgt.dataset.idx;
      [...table.rows].forEach(row => row.cells[idx].remove());
    }
  })
})
```

```css
sup {
  font-size: xx-small
}

.del {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a button added in my html as follows;<button id="btn176" class="btn btn-action" onClick ="deleteColumn()" >Delete Column</button>